# Site scrolling on mobile devices (IOS) JS

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, web

I have parent element with overflow-y: auto, and child element with overflow-x: auto.

Problem: when you start touchmove on child element, you can't scroll parent element at the same time. That thing appears only on IOS devices (iphone, ipad..). Android works good.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've made similar behavior and used this http://iscrolljs.com/ worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
on **child** element add eventListeners onTouchStart, onTouchMove, then:

`touch_start(e){
    this.startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
}`

`touch_move(e){
    let parent_scroll = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].scrollTop; 
    if(e.touches[0].clientY > this.startY){
            document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].scrollTop = parent_scroll - Math.abs(e.touches[0].clientY - this.startY);
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].scrollTop = parent_scroll + Math.abs(e.touches[0].clientY - this.startY);
    }
    this.startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
}`

Also, for IOS needed to prevent body bouncing, so in CSS:

`html, body{
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

And for lazy scroll for each scrolling element add to css:

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

PROFIT! Maybe this solution will help somebody.